# Let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ be the homomorphism such that $\phi(1)=2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ be the homomorphism such that $\phi(1)=2$.
Find the correspondence between $\mathbb{Z}_{12}/K$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ described by the first Isomorphism Theorem, where $\mathbb{Z}_3:=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{12}:=\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, and $K=ker(\phi)$.

I know that $ker(\phi)=\{0,3,6,9\}$ and the cosets of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ are     $\begin{matrix}
        K+0=\{0,3,6,9\} \\
        K+1=\{1,4,7,10\} \\
        K+2=\{2,5,8,11\}
    \end{matrix}$, and I know that the answer is supposed to be     $$\mu(x)=\begin{cases}
    0 & x=0+K \\
    2 & x=1+K \\
    1 & x=2+K
    \end{cases},$$
    But I can't figure out why, even after looking at the first Isomorphism Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For any $a \in \{0, \ldots, 11\}$, notice that:
$$
\phi(a) = \phi(\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_{a \text{ times}}) = \underbrace{\phi(1) + \cdots + \phi(1)}_{a \text{ times}} = \underbrace{2 + \cdots + 2}_{a \text{ times}} = (2a \bmod 3)
$$